# Output of one sample program of javascript is giving wrong answer

Tags: javascript, recursion, timeout

I was reading one book named 'Hands on node.js' by 'Pedro Teixiera'.

I was trying to execute one same program giving in that book that will call a function and that function is calling the same function recursively within some interval again and again.
But when I executed, it gives only one time '1' and stops
Please help me to figure it out why it is not able to call the same function again.
Sample program is as follows:

```
var schedule = function(timeout, callbackfunction) {
    return {
        start: function() {
        setTimeout(callbackfunction, timeout)
        }
    };
};

(function() 
{
    var timeout = 10000; // 1 second
    var count = 0;
    schedule(timeout, function doStuff() {
        console.log(++ count);
        schedule(timeout, doStuff);
    }).start(timeout);
})();
```

Comment: Just FYI 10000 milliseconds is 10 seconds.

Comment: What else did you expect it to do?

Comment: I hope this loop continues because there is not break statement, if I am not wrong.

Comment: There is no loop. Why should there be a break statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually calling the function again. `start()` is the part that starts the timer.

```
schedule( timeout, function doStuff() {
    console.log( ++count );
    schedule( timeout, doStuff ).start();   // <--- added .start() here
}).start();
```

(Also note that the `start()` function doesn't take parameters.)

Answer (score 1):

> with some interval again and again

No, for that you would have used `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

> it gives only one time '1' and stops

Yes, your `doStuff` function doesn't put a new timeout. Your odd `schedule` function needs to be `.start()`ed!